# How do I obtain the balance of tokens in a BSC smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, contract-design, binance, binance-smart-chain

Let's say there is a BEP-20 staking pool contract on the BSC blockchain, and let's say (for extreme simplicity for this example) the address of that contract is "1234".

Upon reviewing the BSC explorer for that address, the BNB value is 0. But let's say there are 5 million BSC tokens stored within that contract. How do I call the balance of those tokens from a DIFFERENT smart contract? Would it just be:

address(1234).balance?

Answer (score 0):

`address(1234).balance` would just return you the BNB amount. To get the amount in this specific token that you are looking for, you would write something like this:

`IERC20(address(tokenContractAddress)).balanceOf(address(1234));` by invoking an ERC20 function balanceOf() that returns the balance of the specific address. You would need to know the contract address of the token that you are interested in though.

Comment: Awesome. Do I need to create an interface to do this? Also, would it be BEP20 instead of IERC20 since this is on the BSC chain?

Comment: Should work with IERC20 as BEP20 extends ERC20, but you can also use BEP20 (but interface only) too if you want. And yes, you will need to have a part of the interface in your code. You can just have this one function balanceOf(address) in it if you are not going to use any other functions